# Swift Combine operator with same functionality like `withLatestFrom` in the RxSwift Framework

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I'm working on an iOS application adopting the MVVM pattern, using SwiftUI for designing the Views and Swift Combine in order to glue together my Views with their respective ViewModels.
In one of my ViewModels I've created a `Publisher` (type `Void`) for a button press and another one for the content of a `TextField` (type `String`). 
I want to be able to combine both Publishers within my ViewModel in a way that the combined Publisher only emits events when the button Publisher emits an event while taking the latest event from the String publisher, so I can do some kind of evaluation on the `TextField` data, every time the user pressed the button. So my VM looks like this:

```
import Combine
import Foundation

public class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var textFieldContent: String? = nil
    @Published var buttonPressed: ()

    init() {
        // Combine `$textFieldContent` and `$buttonPressed` for evaulation of textFieldContent upon every button press... 
    }
}
```

Both publishers are being pupulated with data by SwiftUI, so i will omit that part and let's just assume both publishers receive some data over time.

Coming from the RxSwift Framework, my goto solution would have been the [withLatestFrom](https://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom) operator to combine both observables.
Diving into the Apple Documentation of [Publisher](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher) in the section "Combining Elements from Multiple Publishers" however, I cannot find something similar, so I expect this kind of operator to be missing currently.

So my question: Is it possible to use the existing operator-API of the Combine Framework to get the same behavior in the end like `withLatestFrom`?

Comment: I don't know RxSwift so I don't know what `withLatestFrom` does. What's the desired functionality? You probably want either `combineLatest` or `zip`, but it depends on what you want to do. See http://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsJoiners/operatorscombinelatest.html If neither of those works as desired out of the box, please revise the question to say what's problematic with them and we can add an operator that fixes it.

Comment: Unfortunately neither `combineLatest`, nor `zip` do fullfill my requirements here, because `withLatestFrom` makes sure that the resulting stream only emits events if the first stream (the button clicks in my example) emits events and taking the latest event from the second stream. `combineLatest` emits events upon every latest emission of every stream and zip waits for both stream to emit new events.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/CombineCommunity/rxswift-to-combine-cheatsheet) there is no equivalent.

Comment: @sweeper thanks for the source, that's helpful. I was thinking that maybe it's possible to combine existing operators for the same behavior. Since I was using `withLatestFrom` a lot lately, I'm pretty sure this would be of great benefit for a lot of Combine Users.

Comment: Right, thanks for the clarification. No worries! What I do is append another operator to eliminate "duplicates" where a duplicate is defined as the problematic member of the pair not having changed. That way, only changes come down the pipeline. If you are going to be doing this a lot, it's easy to make a custom operator that expresses a combination like that.

Comment: Would you mind posting a suggestion for a combination like that as an official answer? It would be of great help, thank you. Not 100% sure, if I get your suggestion right, but it wouldn't be sufficient to only emit distinct elements, because the String publisher (representing the `TextField`) emits a new event every time the user enters something and that should not emit a new event in the resulting stream.

Comment: Understood, so it's the _other_ publisher that needs to be a non-duplicate. That's my point. Is that right? We would need your button publisher to pass something distinct (a timestamp would do) so that we can say "yes, this is new" and let it pass thru together with the latest value from the text publisher. That's easy to do.

Comment: Right, but the other publisher (e.g. the `Void` button click event) being a duplicate or not is secondary. The main issue is for the resulting stream to only emit, if one(!) of the publishers emits an event (be it duplicate or not) and only then taking the latest event from the other publisher. A [RxMarble diagram](https://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom) probably says more than 1000 words ;)

Comment: It's not secondary because that's the technique we are going to use to know when to pass the value. If you don't want to use this technique, fine, but it works. I mean, once you accept there is no built in operator that does this, either you want to know how to do it instead or you don't. And what I'm describing is a way to do it.

Comment: Alright, then how about you post a concrete solution and if it‘s the desired behavior in the end, I’m gonna accept the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds great to have a built-in operator for this, but you can construct the same behavior out of the operators you've got, and if this is something you do often, it's easy to make a custom operator out of existing operators.

The idea in this situation would be to use `combineLatest` along with an operator such as `removeDuplicates` that prevents a value from passing down the pipeline unless the button has emitted a new value. For example (this is just a test in the playground):

```
var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
var button = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
func pressTheButton() { button.send() }
var text = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
var textValue = ""
let letters = (97...122).map({String(UnicodeScalar($0))})
func typeSomeText() { textValue += letters.randomElement()!; text.send(textValue)}

button.map {_ in Date()}.combineLatest(text)
    .removeDuplicates {
        $0.0 == $1.0
    }
    .map {$0.1}
    .sink { print($0)}.store(in:&storage)

typeSomeText()
typeSomeText()
typeSomeText()
pressTheButton()
typeSomeText()
typeSomeText()
pressTheButton()
```

The output is two random strings such as `"zed"` and `"zedaf"`. The point is that text is being sent down the pipeline every time we call `typeSomeText`, but we don't *receive* the text at the end of the pipeline unless we call `pressTheButton`.

That seems to be the sort of thing you're after.

---

You'll notice that I'm completely ignoring what the value sent by the button *is*. (In my example it's just a void anyway.) If that value is important, then change the initial map to include that value as part of a tuple, and strip out the Date part of the tuple afterward:

```
button.map {value in (value:value, date:Date())}.combineLatest(text)
    .removeDuplicates {
        $0.0.date == $1.0.date
    }
    .map {($0.value, $1)}
    .map {$0.1}
    .sink { print($0)}.store(in:&storage)
```

The point here is that what arrives after the line `.map {($0.value, $1)}` is exactly like what `withLatestFrom` would produce: a tuple of *both* publishers' most recent values.

Comment: This is not excat `withLatestFrom` https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/withLatestFrom. WithLatestFrom should emit events `only when the source emits`

----
```
pressTheButton() 
typeSomeText()
```
This code prints character but shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

As improvement of @matt answer this is more convenient `withLatestFrom`, that fires on same event in original stream

Updated: Fix issue with combineLatest in iOS versions prior to 14.5

```
extension Publisher {
  func withLatestFrom<P>(
    _ other: P
  ) -> AnyPublisher<(Self.Output, P.Output), Failure> where P: Publisher, Self.Failure == P.Failure {
    let other = other
      // Note: Do not use `.map(Optional.some)` and `.prepend(nil)`.
      // There is a bug in iOS versions prior 14.5 in `.combineLatest`. If P.Output itself is Optional.
      // In this case prepended `Optional.some(nil)` will become just `nil` after `combineLatest`.
      .map { (value: $0, ()) }
      .prepend((value: nil, ()))

    return map { (value: $0, token: UUID()) }
      .combineLatest(other)
      .removeDuplicates(by: { (old, new) in
        let lhs = old.0, rhs = new.0
        return lhs.token == rhs.token
      })
      .map { ($0.value, $1.value) }
      .compactMap { (left, right) in
        right.map { (left, $0) }
      }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

Comment: No, because `drop(untilOutputFrom` cancels its subscription to the second publisher as soon as it gets a value from that publisher. Thus the original goal cannot be achieved. The goal is to keep listening on both publishers and emit the latest value from the first any time the second emits, perpetually.

Comment: Yep already catch that. I change to not so pretty solution without drop first.

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented this and figured I would share my solution to contrast it with the others. Essentially, I'm merging the two Publishers into one with the type `Either<Output, Other.Output>`, using `.scan` to accumulate the latest value of the other publisher, then compact-mapping to only emit elements when the first publisher has emitted. I'm also using an opaque return type rather than using `AnyPublisher`.

```swift
public enum Either<Left, Right> {
    case left(Left)
    case right(Right)
}

public extension Publisher {
    /// Merges two Publishers into one Publisher by emitting the latest element from the second Publisher every time
    /// `self` emits an element.
    func withLatestFrom<Other: Publisher>(_ other: Other) -> some Publisher<Other.Output, Failure> where Failure == Other.Failure {
        typealias ScanOutput = (latest: Other.Output?, emit: Bool)
        return map(Either<Output, Other.Output>.left)
            .merge(with: other.map(Either<Output, Other.Output>.right))
            .scan((nil, false) as ScanOutput) { output, either in
                var output = output
                switch either {
                case .left:
                    output.emit = true
                case .right(let value):
                    output.emit = false
                    output.latest = value
                }
                return output
            }
            .compactMap { $0.emit ? $0.latest : nil }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Kind-of a non-answer, but you could do this instead:

```
buttonTapped.sink { [unowned self] in
    print(textFieldContent)
}
```

This code is fairly obvious, no need to know what `withLatestFrom` means, albeit has the problem of having to capture `self`.

I wonder if this is the reason Apple engineers didn't add `withLatestFrom` to the core Combine framework.