# Swift Combine: enqueue updates to one publisher behind another publisher

Tags: swift, combine

I have a situation where my code needs to make one network call to fetch a bunch of items, but while waiting for those to come down, another network call might fetch an update to those items. I'd love to be able to enqueue those secondary results until the first one has finished. Is there a way to accomplish that with Combine?

Importantly, I am not able to wait before making the second request. It’s actually a connection to a websocket that gets made at the same time as the first request, and the updates come over the websocket outside of my control.

### Update

After examining Matt’s thorough [book](https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsJoiners/operatorsappend.html) on Combine, I settled on `.prepend()`. But as Matt warned me in the comments, `.prepend()` doesn’t even subscribe to the other publisher until after the first one completes. This means I miss any signals sent prior to that. What I need is a `Subject` that enqueues values, but perhaps that’s not so hard to make. Anyway, this is where I got:

Initially I was going to use `.append()`, but I realized with `.prepend()` I could avoid keeping a reference to one of the publishers. So here’s a simplified version of what I’ve got. There might be syntax errors in this, as I’ve whittled it down from my (employer’s) code.

There’s the `ItemFeed`, which handles fetching a list of items and simultaneously handling item update events. The latter can arrive before the initial list of items, and thus must be sequenced via Combine to arrive after it. I attempt to do this by prepending the initial items source to the update `PassthroughSubject`.

Below that is an `XCTestCase` that simulates a lengthy initial item load, and adds an update before that load can complete. It attempts to subscribe to changes to the list of items, and tries to test that the first update is the initial 63 items, and the subsequent update is for 64 items (in this case, “update” results in adding an item).

Unfortunately, while the initial list is published, the update never arrives. I also tried removing the `.output(at:)` operators, but the two sinks are only called once.

After the test case sets up the delayed “fetch,” and subscribes to changes in `feed.items`, it calls `feed.handleItemUpatedEvent`. This calls `ItemFeed.updateItems.send(_:)`, but unfortunately that is lost to oblivion.

```swift
class
ItemFeed
{
    typealias   InitialItemsSource      =   Deferred<Future<[[String : Any]], Error>>
    
                let updateItems         =   PassthroughSubject<[Item], Error>()
                var funnel              :   AnyCancellable?
    
    @Published  var items               =   [Item]()
    
    
    
    init(initialItemSource inSource: InitialItemsSource)
    {
        //  Passthrough subject each time items are updated…
        
        var pub = self.updateItems.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
        //  Prepend the initial items we need to fetch…
        
        let initialItems = source.tryMap { try $0.map { try Item(object: $0) } }
        pub = pub.prepend(initialItems).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
        //  Sink on the funnel to add or update to self.items…
        
        self.funnel =
            pub.sink { inCompletion in
                //  Handle errors
            }
            receiveValue: {
                self.update(items: inItems)
            }
    }
    
    func handleItemUpdatedEvent(_ inItem: Item) {
        self.updateItems.send([inItem])
    }
    
    func update(items inItems: [Item]) {
        //  Update or add inItems to self.items
    }
}

class
ItemFeedTests : XCTestCase
{
    func
    testShouldUpdateItems()
        throws
    {
        //  Set up a mock source of items…
        
        let source = fetchItems(named: "items", delay: 3.0)      //  63 items
        
        let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "testShouldUpdateItems")
        expectation.expectedFulfillmentCount = 2
        
        let feed = ItemFeed(initialItemSource: source)
        
        let sub1 = feed.$items
                    .output(at: 0)
                    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                    .sink { inItems in
                        expectation.fulfill()
                        
                        debugLog("Got first items: \(inItems.count)")
                        XCTAssertEqual(inItems.count, 63)
                    }
        
        let sub2 = feed.$items
                    .output(at: 1)
                    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                    .sink { inItems in
                        expectation.fulfill()

                        debugLog("Got second items: \(inItems.count)")
                        XCTAssertEqual(inItems.count, 64)
                    }
        
        //  Send an update right away…
        
        let item = try loadItem(named: "Item3")
        feed.handleItemUpdatedEvent(item)
        
        XCTAssertEqual(feed.items.count, 0)         //  Should be no items yet
        
        //  Wait for stuff to complete…
        
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10.0)
        
        sub1.cancel()           //  Not necessary, but silence the compiler warning
        sub2.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `.zip`? It takes two publishers / pipelines and does nothing until both have provided a value.

Comment: Here is a list of the "joiner" operators you can choose from: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsJoiners/operatorsjoiners.html

Comment: @matt Upon first glance, it seems `.append()` is what I want. Thanks!

Comment: I thought of that, but note that with append you do not even subscribe to the second publisher until the first publisher has completed.

Comment: @matt I really do need a queueing publisher. I've made a start on one based on your `DoNothing` example, but I'm not sure I’m doing it right. It still doesn’t compile but I think I just don’t have all my generics constraints correct yet. https://gist.github.com/JetForMe/28329bab75db2e013f7251487dceac80?ts=4

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959647/swift-combine-operator-with-same-functionality-like-withlatestfrom-in-the-rxsw ? I can't work out what you are after

Comment: I have two sources of elements. One needs to be queued until another one completes the request. I can't wait to start the second until the first completes, because it provides other events I need right away.

Comment: Yes, but without knowing how many values can come from each publisher in this story, or what else you want to do with those values, it's hard to know what the best way is.

Comment: An arbitrary number of values can come from either, but one will finish. The other will go in indefinitely. I basically want append/prepend but I want it to subscribe immediately, not after the first finishes. Put another way, I want collect-until-another-finishes.

Comment: And when another finishes, what should come down the pipeline at that moment? And thereafter? If P1 emits A B C D and P2 emits X Y Finish, now what happens?

Comment: Publisher A should be gated by Publisher B. Subscriber S subs to A & B, gets whatever B publishes until B completes. Then it gets whatever A had published up to that point (since it subscribed), and then whatever A publishes thereafter, until A or S complete or cancel.

Comment: To use your example, subscriber S would see X Y A B C D (E F G…).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fair bit of trial and error, I found a solution. I created a custom Publisher and Subscription that immediately subscribes to its upstream publisher and begins enqueuing elements (up to some specifiable capacity). It then waits for a subscriber to come along, and provides that subscriber with all the values up until now, and then continues providing values. Here’s a [marble](https://rx-marbles-online.herokuapp.com/?marblescode=marble+Gate%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++source+a%3A++++++%2B--A--BC------D-E-%3E%0D%0A++++source+g%3A++++++%2B-X-Y--Z-%7C%0D%0A++++operator+gate%3A+%2B-X-Y--Z-ABC--D-E-%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Amarble+GateError%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++source+a%3A++++++%2B--A--BC------D-E-%3E%0D%0A++++source+g%3A++++++%2B-X-Y--Z-%23%0D%0A++++operator+gate%3A+%2B-X-Y--Z-%23%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&scale=75&theme=default) diagram:

[image]

I then use this in conjunction with `.prepend()` like so:

```swift
extension
Publisher
{
    func
    enqueue<P>(gatedBy inGate: P, capacity inCapacity: Int = .max)
        -> AnyPublisher<Self.Output, Self.Failure>
        where
            P : Publisher,
            P.Output == Output,
            P.Failure == Failure
    {
        let qp = Publishers.Queueing(upstream: self, capacity: inCapacity)
        let r = qp.prepend(inGate).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        return r
    }
}
```

And this is how you use it…

```swift
func
testShouldReturnAllItemsInOrder()
{
    let gate = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
    let stream = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
    
    var results = [Int]()
    
    let sub = stream.enqueue(gatedBy: gate)
                .sink
                { inElement in
                    debugLog("element: \(inElement)")
                    results.append(inElement)
                }
    stream.send(3)
    stream.send(4)
    stream.send(5)
    
    XCTAssertEqual(results.count, 0)
    
    gate.send(1)
    gate.send(2)
    gate.send(completion: .finished)
    
    XCTAssertEqual(results.count, 5)
    XCTAssertEqual(results, [1,2,3,4,5])
    
    sub.cancel()
}
```

This prints what you would expect:

```
element: 1
element: 2
element: 3
element: 4
element: 5
```

It works well because creating the `.enqueue(gatedBy:)` operator creates the queuing publisher `qp`, which immediately subscribes to `stream` and enqueues any values it sends. It then calls `.prepend()` on `qp`, which first subscribes to `gate`, and waits for it to complete. When it finishes, it then subscribes to `qp`, which immediately provides it with all the enqueued values, and then continues to provide it with values from the upstream publisher.

Here’s the [code](https://gist.github.com/JetForMe/89abfcfbc1df5100afd21c247f7bdc2b?ts=4) I finally ended up with.

```swift
//
//  QueuingPublisher.swift
//  Latency: Zero, LLC
//
//  Created by Rick Mann on 2021-06-03.
//

import Combine
import Foundation



extension
Publishers
{
    final
    class
    Queueing<Upstream: Publisher>: Publisher
    {
        typealias Output = Upstream.Output
        typealias Failure = Upstream.Failure
        
        private     let upstream            :   Upstream
        private     let capacity            :   Int
        private     var queue               :   [Output]                                                =   [Output]()
        private     var subscription        :   QueueingSubscription<Queueing<Upstream>, Upstream>?
        fileprivate var completion          :   Subscribers.Completion<Failure>?                        =   nil
        
        init(upstream inUpstream: Upstream, capacity inCapacity: Int)
        {
            self.upstream = inUpstream
            self.capacity = inCapacity
            
            //  Subscribe to the upstream right away so we can start
            //  enqueueing values…
            
            let sink = AnySubscriber { $0.request(.unlimited) }
                        receiveValue:
                        { [weak self] (inValue: Output) -> Subscribers.Demand in
                            self?.relay(inValue)
                            return .none
                        }
                        receiveCompletion:
                        { [weak self] (inCompletion: Subscribers.Completion<Failure>) in
                            self?.completion = inCompletion
                            self?.subscription?.complete(with: inCompletion)
                        }
            inUpstream.subscribe(sink)
        }
        
        func
        receive<S: Subscriber>(subscriber inSubscriber: S)
            where
                Failure == S.Failure,
                Output == S.Input
        {
            let subscription = QueueingSubscription(publisher: self, subscriber: inSubscriber)
            self.subscription = subscription
            inSubscriber.receive(subscription: subscription)
        }

        /**
            Return up to inDemand values.
        */
        
        func
        request(_ inDemand: Subscribers.Demand)
            -> [Output]
        {
            let count = inDemand.min(self.queue.count)
            let elements = Array(self.queue[..<count])
            self.queue.removeFirst(count)
            return elements
        }
        
        private
        func
        relay(_ inValue: Output)
        {
            //  TODO: The Wenderlich example code checks to see if the upstream has completed,
            //          but I feel like want to send all the values we've gotten first?
            
            //  Save the new value…
            
            self.queue.append(inValue)
            
            //  Discard the oldest if we’re over capacity…
            
            if self.queue.count > self.capacity
            {
                self.queue.removeFirst()
            }
            
            //  Send the buffer to our subscriber…
            
            self.subscription?.dataAvailable()
        }
        

        final
        class
        QueueingSubscription<QP, Upstream> : Subscription
            where
                QP : Queueing<Upstream>
        {
            typealias Output = Upstream.Output
            typealias Failure = Upstream.Failure
            
                    let publisher           :   QP
                    var subscriber          :   AnySubscriber<Output,Failure>?              =   nil
            private var demand              :   Subscribers.Demand                          =   .none
            
            init<S>(publisher inP: QP,
                    subscriber inS: S)
                where
                    S: Subscriber,
                    Failure == S.Failure,
                    Output == S.Input
            {
                self.publisher = inP
                self.subscriber = AnySubscriber(inS)
            }
            
            func
            request(_ inDemand: Subscribers.Demand)
            {
                self.demand += inDemand
                emitAsNeeded()
            }
            
            func
            cancel()
            {
                complete(with: .finished)
            }
            
            /**
                Called by our publisher to let us know new
                data has arrived.
            */
            
            func
            dataAvailable()
            {
                emitAsNeeded()
            }
            
            private
            func
            emitAsNeeded()
            {
                guard let subscriber = self.subscriber else { return }
                
                let newValues = self.publisher.request(self.demand)
                self.demand -= newValues.count
                newValues.forEach
                {
                    let nextDemand = subscriber.receive($0)
                    self.demand += nextDemand
                }
                
                if let completion = self.publisher.completion
                {
                    complete(with: completion)
                }
            }
            
            fileprivate
            func
            complete(with inCompletion: Subscribers.Completion<Failure>)
            {
                guard let subscriber = self.subscriber else { return }
                self.subscriber = nil
                
                subscriber.receive(completion: inCompletion)
            }
        }
    }
}   //  extension Publishers


extension
Publisher
{
    func
    enqueue<P>(gatedBy inGate: P, capacity inCapacity: Int = .max)
        -> AnyPublisher<Self.Output, Self.Failure>
        where
            P : Publisher,
            P.Output == Output,
            P.Failure == Failure
    {
        let qp = Publishers.Queueing(upstream: self, capacity: inCapacity)
        let r = qp.prepend(inGate).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        return r
    }
}

extension
Subscribers.Demand
{
    func
    min(_ inValue: Int)
        -> Int
    {
        if self == .unlimited
        {
            return inValue
        }
        
        return Swift.min(self.max!, inValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Saying "I figured out a secret answer" is not very useful on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't actually have any code, but I was able to figure out a solution. I ended up creating a custom publisher that subscribed to the "gate publisher" and created a subscription that creates a sink for the upstream publisher. I buffer the values from upstream and emit gate publisher values based on demand until it completes, then I switch to sending the buffer downstream based on demand. The tricky part is keeping track of the upstream / gate publisher and sending demand to the right one.

Comment: Your post reminded me to update mine. I've attached the code.